# Jquery/JavaScript - Strip out part of URL from window.location and use as a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the below snippet which makes a call to my API and returns some JSON

```
var authorizationToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
function myapiRequest(endpoint, options) {
  $.ajax($.extend({}, {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('.Name').html(data.user.name);
      $('.Email').html(data.user.email);
      $('.Address').html(data.user.teams[0].name);
    },
    url: "https://api.myapi.com/" + endpoint,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorizationToken,
      "Accept": "application/vnd.myapi+json;version=2"
    }
  },
  options));
}
myapiRequest('/users/' + 'usersID' + '?include%5B%5D=contact_methods&include%5B%5D=teams'); //This is where my userID variable will be called
```

I would like to add something further like....

```
var currentLocation = window.location; // https://myapi.com/users/PLLFFR6
var usersID = PLLFFR6
```

To get the current windows URL and strip the user ID 'PLLFFR6' out and use that as a variable later on my URL always follows the same pattern, /users/ID is the ID part I want to use only

```
myapiRequest('/users/' + 'usersID' + '?include%5B%5D=contact_methods&include%5B%5D=teams');
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using that `method` argument anywhere

Comment: Sorry yes, its from an old run, ill take out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your URL is in the format `https://myapi.com/users/PLLFFR6` then you can `split` the url based on `/` and take the last array element. Example below:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () { test(); }

    function test() {
        var url = "https://myapi.com/users/PLLFFR6".split("/");
        url = url[url.length-1]
        alert(url);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know what my URL is, i know its always in that format though. So I was thinking var currentLocation = window.location; which would give me the current URL and then split it.....

Comment: You can use window.location and then split by `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean something like this...

```
var usersID = location.pathname.split('/').pop()
```

I'd also make use of the `$.ajax` `data` property for those query parameters, ie

```
myapiRequest(`/users/${usersID}`, { // or "'/users/' + usersID" if you don't like template literals
  data: {
    include: ['contact_methods', 'teams']
  }
})
```